# Java can't override method used in constructor: The method setupAnimationFrames() of type Slime must override or implement a supertype method

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, overriding

I'm having problems overriding a method inherited from a parent class in Java. An extract from my parent class:

```
public Character(String spriteLabel, float frameTime, float speed, float x, float y) {
    // Setup font and nameplate
    this.setupAnimationFrames();
    ....
    this.currentFrame = downFrames[0];
}

private void setupAnimationFrames() {
    ...     
}
```

In my child class, I'm trying:

```
public class Slime extends Character {
    @Override
    private void setupAnimationFrames() {
        ...     
    }

    public Slime() {
        super("...", 0.15f, 2,727,300);
    }
}
```

However, Eclipse is telling me:

`The method setupAnimationFrames() of type Slime must override or implement a supertype method`

I've checked and the project/workspace properties are set to use Java 1.6, which appears to be a common cause of this error.

Why won't Java let me override the method?

Comment: Because it's private and you can't override a private method. You can *implement* it, but you can't *override* it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overriding is for those **instance** methods only which are **visible** to child class.Since,the super class `setupAnimationFrames()` method is private,it is not visible to child class and hence overriding doesn't apply here.You are implementing your own method here.Just remove `@Override` annotation for the code to compile.

PS:- Just for verification purpose,you can implement the `setupAnimationFrames()` method with any return type or you can throw any checked exception,it will compile(but of course with @Override annotation)

```
   private String setupAnimationFrames() { 
      //This compiles in child class,return type is different from parent class 
      ...     
   }

    private List setupAnimationFrames() throws Throwable {
      //This compiles in child class ,a checked Throwable has been added to 
     //method signature
        ...     
    }
```